# What patents are IBM claiming Groupon infringed upon?

Tags: patent-infringement, ownership

As per the title, I wondered specifically which patents IBM has alleged Groupon has infringed upon, in its $167 million case: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-ibm-groupon-lawsuit/ibm-seeks-167-million-from-groupon-in-dispute-over-early-internet-patents-idUSKBN1K62VA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.smallcapnetwork.com/Did-Groupon-GRPN-Actually-Infringe-on-an-International-Business-Machines-IBM-Patent/s/via/1789/article/view/p/mid/3/id/756/), the patents allegedly infringed upon are: [US5,796,967](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5796967A/en?oq=US5%2C796%2C967), [US5,961,601](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5961601A/en?oq=US5%2C961%2C601), [US7,072,849](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7072849B1/en?oq=US7%2C072%2C849) and [US7,631,346](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7631346B2/en?oq=US7%2C631%2C346).